# Изменение значения в Map<Object>,List<Object> для каждого ключа в котором такое значении имеется

Tags: java, list, коллекции, map

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student1 = new Student("Ivan", "Ivanov");
    Student student2 = new Student("Nikolay", "Petrov");
    Student student3 = new Student("Kirill", "Antipov");
    Course matematic = new Course("Matematic");
    Course philosophy = new Course("Philosophy");
    Course english = new Course("English");
    Course physics = new Course("Physics");
    Course french = new Course("Franch");

    Map<Student, List<Course>> education = new HashMap<Student, List<Course>>();

    education.put(student1, Arrays.asList(matematic, english, philosophy));
    education.put(student2, Arrays.asList(matematic, english, physics));
    education.put(student3, Arrays.asList());

    Collection<List<Course>> courses = education.values();
    List<Course> updatedCourses = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Course course : updatedCourses) {
        if (course.equals(education.values())) {
            updatedCourses.add(new Course("Franch"));
        } else {
            updatedCourses.add(new Course("Franch"));
        }

        for (Entry<Student, List<Course>> entry : education.entrySet()) {
            education.put(entry.getKey(),entry.setValue(new ArrayList<Course>()));
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry entry : education.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Мне необходимо заменить один объект "курс" на другой. У всех студентов, у которых в значении есть курс `english`, нужно заменить на `frеnch`.

Без использования лямбд и стримов. Спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: У вас странный код: цикл `for (Course course : updatedCourses)` не выполнится, так как `updatedCourses` - пустой список, в следующем цикле записываются пустые списки в качестве значений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вовсе не обязательно создавать новый список для каждого ключа (студента). Можно просто проходиться по `education.values()`, заменяя `english` на `french` в случае, если `english` нашёлся:

```
for (List<Course> value : education.values()) {
    int indexOf = value.indexOf(english);
    if (indexOf >= 0) {
        value.set(indexOf, french);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для замены элементов в списке ещё со времён Java 1.4 существует метод [`Collections::replaceAll(List<T> list, T oldVal, T newVal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#replaceAll-java.util.List-T-T-).

Соответственно, достаточно проитерироваться по коллекции значений мапы `education`:

```java
for (List<Course> courses : education.values()) {
    Collections.replaceAll(courses, english, french);
}
```

С использованием `Iterable::forEach` такая замена превратится в однострочник, правда, при помощи лямбды:

```java
education.values().forEach(courses -> Collections.replaceAll(courses, english, french));
```